# In Ubuntu 16.04, how can I set keyboard shortcuts for maximizing a window horizontally or vertically?

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, window

In Ubuntu 12.04 I used Shift+Super+Arrow for this purpose, but I have not found out if it is possible in Ubuntu 16.04. Using Ubuntu 16.04 with two 5:4 monitors (to be able to switch one of them to another PC by choosing the 'DVI' or the 'VGA' input), I noticed it was possible to use just one of the monitors or just the left or right half of any of the two monitors by merely pulling the window so that the cursor touches the top, left or right border of one of the monitors. But I have not figured out how to use only the top or the bottom half of one of the monitors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a selected window, try Ctrl+Alt+any number key below NumLock or right of it.
(Keyboard shortcuts are shown by holding one of the Super = "Windows" keys; the left of them is between the left Ctrl and Alt.)
 Vertically, a window can be maximized by mouse dragging its corner to the top.
Horizontally it does not work: it is reasonable for using more displays to horizontally expand the display area; that enables making a window effectively far wider then any of the single  displays. To another display you can move the window by mouse dragging, maybe after clicking at maximizing-restore-minimizing icons at the left upper corner.
I cannot imagine a system of controlling windows sizes and positions which would be more universal or more friendly or quicker or which would more effectively use the displaying area.